# Xamarin iOS random crashes with SIGBUS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have strange crashes on devices in my Xamarin App. It happens at any time of app, without any connection to particular actions inside the app. What can I do to find a reason for that crash?

The crash log was caught through HockeyApp.

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 11.0.1 (15A402)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGBUS
Exception Codes: BUS_ADRALN at 0x1
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
Selector name found in current argument registers: prev_signal_handlers

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                                  0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 0
1   libsystem_platform.dylib             0x0000000180fafb60 _sigtramp + 48
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x0000000180e80a3c mach_msg + 68
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018132fce4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
4   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018132d8b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1420
5   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018124e2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 432
6   GraphicsServices                     0x00000001830dff84 GSEventRunModal + 96
7   UIKit                                0x000000018a7fb880 UIApplicationMain + 204
8   FaxiOS                               0x00000001006c76f4 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr (<unknown>:1)
9   FaxiOS                               0x00000001006742ec UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr (UIApplication.cs:79)
10  FaxiOS                               0x00000001006742ac UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string (UIApplication.cs:63)
11  FaxiOS                               0x00000001002c3544 Fax_iOS_Application_Main_string__ (<unknown>:1)
12  FaxiOS                               0x00000001005a9094 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 240
13  FaxiOS                               0x00000001012f3b38 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini-runtime.c:2509)
14  FaxiOS                               0x000000010136e620 do_runtime_invoke (object.c:2860)
15  FaxiOS                               0x0000000101371844 do_exec_main_checked (object.c:3018)
16  FaxiOS                               0x00000001012d7770 mono_jit_exec (driver.g.c:1037)
17  FaxiOS                               0x0000000101424f48 xamarin_main (monotouch-main.m:480)
18  FaxiOS                               0x00000001011a4108 main (main.m:179)
19  libdyld.dylib                        0x0000000180d7256c start + 0
```

Comment: SIGBUS : the most *likely* cause is a disposed object, a GC'd object, a null pointer, etc.. symbolize the crash report